# Halogenation of organic acid derivatives

Tags: organic-chemistry, synthesis, halides, halogenation

Chloropicrin can be produced through the reaction of sodium hypochlorite with nitromethane. On the surface, this seems to me to proceed through a mechanism analogous to the haloform reaction, with one notable difference being that, in the case of the generation of chloropicrin, the C-N bond is not cleaved.

On a related note, I found a paper that claims that acetate esters are also capable of undergoing the haloform reaction.

Because of these two facts, I am wondering if a process analogous to the creation of chloropicrin can occur with other organic acid derivatives. As an example, could methyl methanesulfonate react with bleach to give methyl trichloromethanesulfonate? If yes, are there any other organic acid derivatives for which this process can occur?

**Source:**
Nagata, D., & Nishiwaki, N. (2021). Are acetic acid derivatives really negative to the iodoform test? SN Applied Sciences, 3(9). doi:10.1007/s42452-021-04777-0

Comment: Mesylate? Not really, but any C-acid with nucleophilic conjugated base, and without electrophilic centers...

Comment: @Mithoron Could you explain why, preferably with something to back up your claim?